# Deducing the factorial expression

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

I wish to deduce the term (2n!/(n+1)!*n!) 
I began by expanding the numerator and denominator in terms of there factorials only to reach nowhere.

So any help will be appreciated, or any idea about how i can go towards deducing (2n!/(n+1)!*n!) avoiding the factorial calculation

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number, https://oeis.org/A000108

Comment: This sequence doesn't provide a deduced formula that doesn't involve factorial calculations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a mathematics questions, not (yet) a programming one.